# What is a good read on the topics of ethics in the time of globalization?

Tags: ethics, reference-request, philosophy-of-culture

I would like to mature my thinking regarding ethics in a pluri-cultural world.

Which are interesting reads addressing questions such as:

- Should we do commerce exchange with cultures that do not respect women rights ?
- Under which terms can cultural imperialism be justified (i.e. fighting for world-wide human rights and democracy) ?
- How to relate to individuals/groups/cultures with radically different perspectives (e.g. no notion of animals rights) ?

I have a small preference for books/essays authored by european philosophers (of any time), but any recommendation is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Peter Singer's *One World: The Ethics of Globalization* ([Worldcat link](http://www.worldcat.org/title/one-world-the-ethics-of-globalization/oclc/50527596)) is a good, brief and thoughtful read on this topic. It discusses humanitarian intervention and moral responsibility and the challenges of those in an interconnected world.